# Different cursor in Skype

Tags: skype

I have changed my default cursor theme to the DMZ black, but when my mouse hovers over any Skype window, it turns into DMZ white (only while hovering). When I try to take a screenshot of it, the cursor shows up as black on the image, which is rather weird.

Anybody who's got an idea how to fix it?

Comment: I am quite sure that skype uses QT for window rendering, because of this you might have to change som qt/kde setting. But how I have no idea.

Comment: yuck! I already disliked skype in ubuntu, now I absolutely hate it :|

Comment: This doesn't happen for me.  What versions are you using (skype and ubuntu)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is common problem with Skype, I've had it too. To fix it, you need to install kde's system-settings (sadly, no option for the cursor in qt-config, and it's probably not so trivial, or wise to edit the qt-config by hand). In KDE's system settings, choose the mouse option to change your Qt cursor theme.

Another possible fix is to change the default theme for your entire system. Run [galternatives](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/galternatives) and change the x-cursor theme to the one you currently use.

Comment: The galternatives did the trick, and if I'm lucky, it'll fix another annoyance I've had: that the cursor changes briefly during login, even though I've changed the gdm-cursor theme to DMZ-black.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: galternatives did the trick

Answer (score 10):

Strange, but on my system (13.04) the issue has been healed just through installation of `libxcursor1:i386`.

Comment: worked for me as well

Comment: worked for me too, the simplest solution so far!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using th Mint KDE 16 64 bit, and I install skype from software center, and have that problem. Then I run install command on terminal shell:

```
sudo apt-get install libxcursor1:i386
```

After that I reboot the computer, and it's done.

Comment: no need to reboot, just restart skype

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone else would be also interested in another possible solution: when I installed Skype from Ubuntu repository (11.10) I also had the same issue - but I've tried downloading and installing Skype client from skype.com page and then after installing it - normal KDE settings applies on it as well...