# running Gnome, different cursor in Kate

Tags: gnome, kate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Different cursor in Skype](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12758/different-cursor-in-skype)

I have my cursor set to a big, high-contrast size. I'm running Gnome, and when I mouse over my Kate window, the cursor changes into a very small, difficult to see size. Any chance this is fix-able...?

Comment: Ah, my apologies. My impression was that the Skype person was using KDE, while I'm using Gnome...?