# Skype on 64 bit has non default mouse cursor theme

Tags: 64-bit, mouse, themes, skype, cursor

I have installed Skype from Canonical Partner repository on my 64-bit Ubuntu system.

When I hover the mouse over the Skype window, the mouse cursor theme changes from default white to black.

How can I fix it?

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/302370/skype-does-not-use-default-ambiance-theme, http://askubuntu.com/questions/12758/different-cursor-in-skype

Answer (score 7):

To fix Skype's non-default mouse cursor theme on Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit,

Firstly you have to enable MultiArch by running (in a terminal window) the command:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Then refresh apt repository list by typing:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And finally you have to install the following package:

```
sudo apt-get install libxcursor1:i386
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been known for a long time and the fix is still the same. I followed a [how-to](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/08/how-to-change-mouse-cursor-theme-in.html) written for Ubuntu 10.10 and the issue was solved.

1. First, you need to find the name of your cursor theme. I found it in Gnome Tweak Tool, the how-to suggests to find it in */usr/share/icons*. For example, it could be *Chameleon-Pearl-Regular*.
2. Now you need to edit the /usr/share/icons/default/index.theme file with root access. Press ALT + F2 and enter:

   > gksu gedit /usr/share/icons/default/index.theme
3. In my case, the file looked like that:

   > [Icon Theme]
   >
   > Inherits=Adwaita
4. You only need to replace the name of the cursor theme by the new one:

   > [Icon Theme]
   >
   > Inherits=Chameleon-Pearl-Regular
5. Finally you need to log out and log back in for the change to take effect.