# Skype does not use default Ambiance theme

Tags: 64-bit, themes, skype, gtk

I have installed Skype from Canonical Partner repository on my 64-bit Ubuntu system.

Skype uses the Cleanlooks theme instead of the default Ambiance theme.

How can I fix it?

Comment: have you checked in settings of skype or looked in any settings?

Comment: Is Skype a GTK2 app? Then it would use the GNOME 2 theme settings, which may be different from most apps.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail, Ambiance still has a provision to theme gtk2 apps. See `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/`. AFAIK, several major apps (Firefox, Chrome, LibreOffice) are still gtk2-based.

Comment: OP, where is your "default Ambiance" theme located? Is it in `/usr/share/themes` or are you using it from `~/.themes`?

Answer (score 4):

To fix Skype's GTK+ theme on Ubuntu 13.04.

first you have to enable MultiArch by running (in a terminal window) the command:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

then refresh apt repository list by typing:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then you have to install the following package:

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-murrine:i386
```